# How to convert hex values inside a string into a actual byte

Tags: c, scanf

I need to convert a hex contained in a string like "FAFBFCFD" into a array or into a uint32.

I tried with a sscanf like that:

```
uint8_t ns[4];
sscanf("FAFBFCFD", "%X%X%X%X", &ns[0], &ns[1], &ns[2], &ns[3]);
```

But all i get in the array is ff ff ff 7f

Edit:

Like @Clifford said, the values returned by sscanf in this case is a int and if you pass a pointer to uint8_t the program will gonna crash.

Comment: The normal practice in SO is for you to show us your attempt, and you get help and advice - not a free code or homework service.

Comment: Converting *"into an array"* or *"into a uint32"* are two very different things. So step 1 is to decide what you're doing.

Comment: Hint: `uint32_t digit = strchr(character, "0123456789abcdefABCDEF"); value = value - 6*(value > 15);` can help to convert individual digits. You yet need to combine the individual digits as `value = value * 16 + digit;`, assuming you start reading the string from its front. Consider, too, that `strchr` might return -1 if the character is not found, i. e. an illegal character contained, so you might need some error handling.

Comment: From the man page, the `%X` conversion *"matches an optionally signed hexadecimal integer; the next pointer must be a pointer to unsigned int."* So there are two problems. **1)** The first `%X` is going to take the entire string. It doesn't know that you only want it to read 2 characters. That can be fixed by specifying a maximum width, e.g. `%2X`. **2)** The arguments that follow the format string must match what the format string requires. In your case, all of the pointers must be pointers to `unsigned int` because that's what `%X` requires.

Comment: `ns` needs to be type `int` then `sscanf("FAFBFCFD", "%2X%2X%2X%2X", &ns[0], &ns[1], &ns[2], &ns[3]);`, you can then cast the `ns` elements into `uint8_t` as required.  Closed too soon IMO - your fix to the question was adequate.  My answer used a loop to parse two digits at a time into a temporary int then cast into an `uint8_t` array.  Allowing it to cope with variable length strings.  If it gets reopened, I'll post it.

Comment: He guys - it took 8 minutes to close this question on this new user - he was asked to improve the question and did so - giving fair time would not go amis.

Comment: What I would have posted if you had not been the victim of impatience:  https://onlinegdb.com/Up5v9toQo

Comment: Thanks all for the answers, @Clifford your solution works like a charm, thanks!

Comment: Voted to reopen - I think the question and answer (perhaps with a little bit more commentary on how it works and why the original code doesn't) are both good.

Comment: Responding to your edit: It's not only that `%X` returns `int`, it's the fact that `%X` means that it will only accept `unsigned int *` so anything else you pass will result in undefined behavior. And the program may not necessarily crash because anything can happen with undefined behavior. Generally it's better when it does crash, otherwise the program will seem to run properly while there's a problem that's slowly growing to the point that the program eventually crashes at an unrelated point or shows a logic error, and then it's hard to pinpoint the mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enable compiler warnings, you'll find them to be very useful in situations like this. When I enable `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic-errors` on x64 GCC 11.1, I get this warning:

```
<source>:9:26: warning: format '%X' expects argument of type 'unsigned int *', but argument 3 has type 'uint8_t *' {aka 'unsigned char *'} [-Wformat=]
    9 |     sscanf("FAFBFCFD", "%X%X%X%X", &ns[0], &ns[1], &ns[2], &ns[3]);
      |                         ~^         ~~~~~~
      |                          |         |
      |                          |         uint8_t * {aka unsigned char *}
      |                          unsigned int *
      |                         %hhX
```

And this makes the issue pretty clear. `%X` is meant only for `unsigned int *`, but you're parameters are of type `uint8_t *` (AKA `unsigned char *`). The result is undefined behavior. The warning also tells you to use `%hhx` instead, but you'll also have to specify that you only want to read two characters for each argument. So your call to `sscanf` should look like this:

```
sscanf("FAFBFCFD", "%2hhx%2hhx%2hhx%2hhx", &ns[0], &ns[1], &ns[2], &ns[3]);
```

Moreover, there are macros defined in `inttypes.h` which expand to the correct format specifiers for the `uintX_t`/`intX_t` types, and a few more. So you can use the `SCNx8`  macro, which is guaranteed to be the correct format for `uint8_t` as opposed to `hhx`:

```
sscanf("FAFBFCFD",
       "%2"SCNx8"%2"SCNx8"%2"SCNx8"%2"SCNx8"",
       &ns[0], &ns[1], &ns[2], &ns[3]);
```

Though it certainly makes things look a bit uglier...